# Can't create a simple client in perforce

Tags: perforce-client-spec

P4 novice here !

I want to create a workspace and sync in dirs/files from a p4 repo.  Simple stuff, which I can't get to work.  What's wrong with this picture ?

The p4 server & port : myp4server.xyz.com:1712
The p4 repo is //etc/freeze_check

I create a dir (in linux) /home/me/freeze_check and cd into it.
I type "p4 client" and fill it in like this...

```
Client: my_client_name
Owner:  me
Description:
    Created by me.
Root:   /home/me/freeze_check
Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir
SubmitOptions:  revertunchanged
LineEnd:    local
View:
        //etc/freeze_check/... //my_client_name/...
```

I left the "host" out but have this in /home/me/P4OCNFIG

```
P4PORT=myp4server.xyz.com:1712
P4CLIENT=my_client_name
```

I also "setenv P4CLIENT P4CLIENT" (I saw a working P4 workspace that did this)

Then I exit the editor.  It says it saved the client.

Now, If I type "p4 client -o my_client_name", I see what I just defined.
If I type "p4 client -o" (no client name), it comes up with something different, the same thing that I started out with.

Q: How can I associate the client that I just created with the dir that I just created ?
Q: Is the P4CONFIG file necessary?  Is the setenv P4CONFIG necessary?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to use P4CONFIG, but it can be convenient if you use multiple clients on the same workstation.

Try `setenv P4CLIENT my_client_name`

Comment: Yup, that did it.  (Thanks BTW)  But why wasn't this picked up in the P4CONFIG file ?

Comment: Was P4CONFIG set (pointing the the name of a P4CONFIG file)? You can use the command "p4 set" to display which P4 settings are, uh, set.